# How to code Euler #3 for any value?

Tags: c++

```
/*
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    unsigned long num = 600851475143;
    unsigned long i;
    long double root = sqrt(num);
    long double tempRoot = 0;
    unsigned long factor = 0;
    unsigned long largest = 0;

    for (i=2; i<root; i++)
    {
        if (num%i == 0)
        {   
            num = num/i;
            factor = i;
            cout << factor << endl;

            if (factor > largest)
                {
                    largest = factor;
                }
        }
    }

    cout << largest << endl;    

return 0;
}
```

This solution works because coincidentally the factors of 600851475143 are all prime numbers. But when debugging the code I was inputting various values for the variable num (=600851475143). For example, when I input 135 it showed me all the factors, including the non-prime ones. How do I add a prime number checker for the factors? I tried using the same method that I used here within a nested if, but failed miserably. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, please indicate if I am using unnecessarily large variable types in case of some variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, 600851475143 has non-prime factors too! For example, 1234169 divides it.

Comment: You probably want `long long` instead of `unsigned long` for `600851475143`.

Comment: The loop condition should be `i<=root`, otherwise you'll get the wrong answer if `num` is the square of a prime. I'd prefer `i*i<=num`, to avoid the possibility of floating-point rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do a prime-number check. As you are factoring, just make sure to continue dividing out a candidate until it no longer divides the number. This is really easy to do in code: just change the `if (num%i == 0)` to `while (num%i == 0)`.